# Why do NON -Transition elements exhibit variable oxidation state?

Tags: transition-metals, crystal-field-theory

I know transition elements exhibit variable oxidation states because valence electrons are in d block and s which are very close so they have similar energies ,thus with slightly different energies electrons can be removed and thus different oxidation states ,but why do non-transition elements exhibit variable oxidation state ..

Is it due to 
1.Hybridisation
2.D-block
?

Answer (score 2):

Why not?

Elements with only a single oxidation state are rare things.  In fact technically, only helium and neon are known in just a single oxidation state, zero for each.  Everything else is known to form at least some (conventional) compounds, and then you have the zero oxidation state of the pure element plus any oxidation states there are in the compounds.

Multiple nonzero oxidation states are the norm for most nonmetals, as well.  Just check out common compounds of, say, carbon, nitrogen, sulfur, phosphorous, ... .

I would not ask why, just revel in it.

Comment: why? is asking why a bad question?

Comment: and are there factors other then hybridisation and closer orbitals because of which non -transition elements have variable oxidation states.?